# Connect to SQL Server from another computer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my websites database server named razatube.com, I don't have the server on my machine. How can I connect to this server from another machine to fetch database items? Any help would be highly appreciated.
PS: I don't usually use Microsoft products so pardon me if the answer stares directly on my face :(

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the IP address or URL of the database server along with port number, login name and password of the SQL Server database. When you have all these, you can go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and get your desired connection string and use it into your web programs to connect your web server and your database server.

Comment: I need an Android app to connect to the server.

Comment: Don't you think there could be too many security threats if you use an android app to connect directly to your database?